# getting the Length of all lists in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
listdict = {
  'list_1' : ['1'],
  'list_2' : ['1','2'],
  'list_3' : ['2'],
  'list_4' : ['1', '2', '3', '4']
}
    
print(len(listdict))
```

This is my code for example. I want it to print:

```
8
```

I have tried length as u can see but it prints 4 of course the amount of lists but I want it to print
the amount of items in the lists. Is there a way where I can do this with one statement instead of doing them all seperately? Thanks in advance.

I tried using len(dictionaryname) but that did not work

Comment: Try to get total_len first- ```total_len = [len(v) for v in listdict.values() ]``` then ```sum(total_len)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 4 lists as values in your dictionary, so you have to sum the lengths:

```py
print(sum(map(len, listdict.values())))
```

Prints:

```
8
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider utilizing another inbuilt function [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) ([`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) is a built in function):

```
>>> listdict = {
...   'list_1' : ['1'],
...   'list_2' : ['1','2'],
...   'list_3' : ['2'],
...   'list_4' : ['1', '2', '3', '4']
... }
>>> sum(len(xs) for xs in listdict.values())
8
```

As an aside, since python employs [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) using [Hungarian naming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) for variables in Python is kinda [sus](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=sus) [ngl](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=ngl)...